# Why does the do/while loop keep adding the input each time the switch statement fires?

Tags: java

Write a class with a constructor that accepts a String object as its argument. The class should have a method that 
returns the number of vowels in the string, and another method that returns the number of consonants in the string.
Demonstrate the class in a program that performs the following steps:

1. The user is asked to enter a string.
2. The program displays the following menu: 
   a: Count the number of vowels in the string
   b: Count the number of consonants in the string
   c: Count both the vowels and consonants in the string
   d: Enter another string
   e: Exit the program.
3. The program performs the operation selected by the user and repeats until the user selects e, to exit the program.

When the user enters a string and checks for consonants, or vowels, or both once, it works just fine.

But when it is passed again, the program doubles the value.

Thoughts?

Class:

```
public class CounterClass
{   
  String string;
  int vow = 0; 
  int con = 0;
  char letter = ' ';
  int enter = 0;
   /**
    * This is a Constructor
    * It accepts a string object. 
    */

   public CounterClass(String aString)
   {
     this.string = aString; 

   }

   /* @returns an int
    * This method checks for char and then adds it to a vowel counter */

   public int getVowels(String aString)
   {
     int length = aString.length();

     for( int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
     {
       char c = aString.charAt(i);
       if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i'|| c == 'o'
             || c == 'u' ||c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I'
             || c == 'O' || c == 'U')
       {
         vow++;
       }

   }
   return vow; 

   }
   /* @returns an int
    * This method checks for char and then adds it to a con counter */
     public int getConsonants(String aString)
   {
     int length = aString.length();

     for( int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
     {
       char c = aString.charAt(i);
       if (c == 'B' || c == 'C' || c == 'D'|| c == 'F'
             || c == 'G' ||c == 'H' || c == 'J' || c == 'K'
             || c == 'L' || c == 'M'|| c == 'N' || c == 'P'|| c == 'Q'
             || c == 'R' ||c == 'S' || c == 'T' || c == 'V'
             || c == 'W' || c == 'X'|| c == 'Z' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd'|| c == 'f'
             || c == 'g' ||c == 'h' || c == 'j' || c == 'k'
             || c == 'l' || c == 'm'|| c == 'n' || c == 'p'|| c == 'q'
             || c == 'r' ||c == 's' || c == 't' || c == 'v'
             || c == 'w' || c == 'x'|| c == 'z')
       {
         con++;
       }

   }
   return con; 

   }
```

}

Main Program :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class NumberCounters
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {


    //Declaring variable for later use. 
    String input = " "; 
    String letters = " ";
    char letter = ' ';


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //This creates an instance of CounterClass
    CounterClass string = new CounterClass(input); 


    //Tests
    System.out.println(string.getVowels(input));
    System.out.println(string.getConsonants(input));


    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a string"); // Getting a string input from the user.


    //Does a loop until the user selects 'e'
    do{

      //sets 'letters' to the inputdialog from the menu
      letters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
  "a: Count the number of vowels in the string\n" +
  "b: Count the number of consonants in the string\n" +
  "c: Count both the vowels and consonants in the string\n"+
  "d: Enter another string\n" + "e: Exit the program");


     letter = letters.charAt(0); // letters is a string so I used charAt to grab the first letter from the input.


     switch(letter)
     {
       case 'A':
       case 'a': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + string.getVowels(input) + " vowels in your string");
       break;

       case 'B':
       case 'b': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + string.getConsonants(input) +
                                               " consonants in your string");
       break;

       case 'C':
       case 'c': JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You have " + string.getConsonants(input) 
                                                       + " Consonants and " + string.getVowels(input) 
                                                       + " vowels in your string");
       break;

       case 'D':
       case 'd': input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a string");
       break;

       case 'E':
       case 'e': 
       System.exit(0);
     }


     }while( letter != 'e'); 
}
}
```

Comment: Well, when do `con` and `vow` get set to 0?

Comment: doh! That worked like a charm. I just set them to 0 inside the methods and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting your values back to 0 in each method you could also remove the getConsonants method and just place an else(example of edited code below)

```
 public int getVowels(String aString)
 {
//set values to back to 0 before checking
vow = 0;
con = 0;
 int length = aString.length();

 for( int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
 {
   char c = aString.charAt(i);
   if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i'|| c == 'o'
         || c == 'u' ||c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I'
         || c == 'O' || c == 'U')
   {
     vow++;
   }
   else if(c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9' || c == '0' ||){
  //in case you add numbers put here 
 }
   else
   {
       con++;
   }

}
return vow;
```